# Passing command line arguments in django runscript

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-extensions

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to a script using `django runscript` ?
The script I am trying to run uses `argparse` to accept command line arguments.

**Command line execution of the script:**

```
./consumer --arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2
```

Both `arg1` and `arg2` are required options.

We tried using `script-args` but unable to figure out how to use it in this context.

Comment: `runscript` can't run any Python script but requires a special script that implements a `run(*args)` method. You can't pass arguments to the script that way.

Answer (score 4):

Update in 2020: use --script-args

https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html#passing-arguments

Comment: Django-extensions is a good package, but its documentation is poor.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Django's [Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/)

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--arg1', help="Something helpful")

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print options['arg1']
```

And when run:

```
$python manage.py your_command --arg1 arg
arg
```

Command works nicely for this sort of thing, as Selcuk said, you can't use arguments in this fashion using RunScript extension.